# how to get file paths from files dragged from windows explorer into JFrame in Java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

I need to get the dropped files' paths. I have implemented the drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) method in my JFrame which implements DropTargetListener which has the following code:

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
    Transferable tr = e.getTransferable();
    e.acceptDrop (DnDConstants.ACTION_REFERENCE);

    try {
          System.out.println(tr.getTransferData(DataFlavor.getTextPlainUnicodeFlavor()));
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

     e.getDropTargetContext().dropComplete(true);
}
```

Comment: Check http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/GetAbsolutePath Is it that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The section from the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Drop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html) has a working example. It looks like it uses `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`.